# Java EE containers don't allow using Java SE conccurency API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8

In the book of Arun Gupta "Java EE 7 Essentials" I found this:

*Java EE containers such as the EJB or web container do not allow using common Java
SE concurrency APIs such as java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor,
java.lang.Thread, or java.util.Timer directly.*

What does mean "do not allow"? I don't understand how container can forbid me create new thread or use standard ExecutorService. What will happen with my standard threads? Can anybody explain these?

Some remark. I understand why use `ManagedExecutorService` instead of `ExecutorService` for example can be mor efficient, I don't understand what problems can occur if I'll use SE

Comment: The container is running your code, so of course it can forbid you to use certain classes. You'll get error messages and your software won't run.

Comment: What type of error I'll get? I used standard executor service and all works fine on several systems in production

Comment: Depends on the container, besides you can't really be sure that it "works fine".

Comment: Can you give some examples please?

Comment: If the container has its own `SecurityManager`, it can control (and forbid) plenty of things your code does. If your code works seemingly fine, then fair enough, but at least you've been warned that you shouldn't be doing that. What container does your "works fine" code run on?

Comment: ty, but I'm interested in more depth understanding of this problem. I want to know how it works deep inside. It will be great if you can give more detailed example in answer to my question, not comment.

Comment: If you want to understand it in depth, then you'll probably want to read the documentation of the various Java EE containers.

Comment: I tried find answer here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EE+Concurrency+Utilities
but it doesn't say what problems can occur. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is explained fairly clearly if you continue reading.  Later in the paragraph:

> ... This is because all application code is run on a thread managed by the container, and each container typically expects all access to container-supplied objects to occur on the same thread. This allows the container to manage the resources and provide centralized administration. Further, using resources in a nonmanaged way is discouraged, because it can potentially undermine the enterprise features that the platform is designed to provide, such as availability, security, reliability, and scalability.

I can see why you raised your initial question though, the wording on the initial statement is a bit confusing.

**To answer your question:**
Java EE containers don't have to explicitly prevent you from calling these APIs in the way you might expect (such as throwing an exception if you try to use them).  Some Java EE containers might use a SecurityManager or something to prevent access to certain classes, but doing so it not required by the spec.

However, the Java EE container will not be able to manage anything you do with these "unmanaged" JavaSE APIs, and it's considered bad practice to use them when there are managed equivalents available to you (such as `ManagedExecutorService` vs `ExecutorService`)

To illustrate, the following code *will* work just fine in a Servlet:

```
Runnable printSomething = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};

new java.lang.Thread(printSomething, "JavaSE-Thread").start();
```

(tested using WebSphere Liberty)

However, doing this is considered bad practice because:

> Using resources in a nonmanaged way is discouraged, because it can potentially undermine the enterprise features that the platform is designed to provide, such as availability, security, reliability, and scalability.